# Magento 2.4.0 custom sorting function setOrder is not working

Tags: php, sorting, magento, magento2

Magento 2.4.0 `setOrder` is not working

I have already work with these two files but when I print select query it's getting `WHERE null`

> \vendor\magento\module-catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar.php

> \vendor\magento\module-catalog\Model\Config.php

di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Config">
        <plugin name="Evolve_Sorting::addCustomSortOptions" type="Evolve\Sorting\Plugin\Model\Config" />
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar">
        <plugin name="Evolve_Sorting::implementCustomSortOptions" type="Evolve\Sorting\Plugin\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Config.php

```
<?php
namespace Evolve\Sorting\Plugin\Model;

class Config
{
    /**
     * Adding custom options and changing labels
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $catalogConfig
     * @param [] $options
     * @return []
     */
    public function afterGetAttributeUsedForSortByArray(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $catalogConfig, $options)
    {
        $options['order_by'] = __('order by');
        $options['name_az'] = __('Name A-Z');
        $options['name_za'] = __('Name Z-A');
        $options['newest'] = __('New arrivals');
        $options['price_asc'] = __('Price low-high');
        $options['price_desc'] = __('Price high-low');

        return $options;
    }
}
```

Toolbar.php

```
<?php

namespace Evolve\Sorting\Plugin\Product\ProductList;

class Toolbar
{
    /**
     * Plugin
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $subject
     * @param \Closure $proceed
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection $collection
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar
     */
    public function aroundSetCollection(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $toolbar,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $collection
    )
    {
        $this->_collection = $collection;
        $currentOrder = $toolbar->getCurrentOrder();
        $currentDirection = $toolbar->getCurrentDirection();
        $result = $proceed($collection);

        if ($currentOrder) {
            switch ($currentOrder) {

                case 'name_az':
                    $this->_collection
                        ->addAttributeToSort('name', 'asc');
                    break;

                case 'name_za':
                    $this->_collection
                        ->addAttributeToSort('name', 'desc');
                    break;

                case 'newest':
                    $this->_collection
                        ->getSelect()
                        ->order('e.created_at DESC');
                    break;

                case 'price_asc':
                    $this->_collection
                        ->addAttributeToSort('price', 'asc');
                    break;

                case 'price_desc':
                    $this->_collection
                        ->addAttributeToSort('price', 'desc');
                    break;

                default:
                    $this->_collection
                        ->setOrder($currentOrder, $currentDirection);
                    break;

            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you get it working?

Comment: Hello, I'm having the same problem with Magento 2.4.3. If you have a solution, it would be fantastic if you could share it.

Comment: @MonarkBhawani, have you fixed the issue? I am getting  the same issue after upgrading into Magento 2.4.4

Comment: @VinodKumar I have a solution only for name A to Z, name Z to A, price high to low, and price low to high.

Comment: @VinodKumar please check the solution I think it is useful for you.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/358034/magento2-4-how-to-sort-product-by-best-selling-and-best-reviewed-produc